# Uniqueness of a regular measure extension

Tags: measure-theory

I know by the Carathéodory's extension theorem that if I have a pre-measure $\mu_0$ on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$, then it is extendable to a measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$. If $\mu_0$ is sigma-finite, then the extension is unique.

Since I know of several counter examples when $\mu_0$ is not sigma-finite, I was wondering whether some regularity  implies uniqueness without assuming sigma finiteness. i.e., if $\mu_0$ is a pre-measure on the collection of open sets of Hausdorff space and there exists a Radon measure extending $\mu_0$, is such a Radon extension unique?

I was also wondering whether given a pre-measure on open sets,  we  always obtain an outer regular extension? (Even if it is not necessarily finite on compact sets)

Comment: The minimal extension works well for semi-rings and a function $\mu$ on the semiring that is a nonnegative, additive  and countably sub additive function. Those conditions allow from extension to measure on a sigma algebra containing the semi ring. It is unique in the sense that the extension is maximal.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I'm not sure I fully understood your comment. When you say the extension is maximal, do you mean that there could no further extension to a larger sigma algebra? Or that it dominates any other measure extending the pre-measure? And thank you for your answer also.

Comment: If $\mu^*$ is the Caratheodory extension of $\mu$  and $\nu$ another extension of $\mu$ to the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}$, then $\nu\leq \mu$. You can find all this in Kallenberg's Foundations of Theory of Probability.